# Flex and ASP.Net-Membership via WebORB

Tags: c#, sql, apache-flex, dll, asp.net-membership

Have anyone done this? I'm putting the membershiplogic in a C# .dll, and the connection info in an app.config.

When I try to use the C# .dll with another Windows C# console debug project I put the App.config in the consoles application directory, and calling the C# .dll-methods and it suceeds, I get a connection and it validates my users in the Database.

However, when I try to use the C# .dll and App.config with WebOrb and Flex, I'm lost. I can't find where to put the App.config, I always get "Could not connect to the SQL-Database" :(

Or is there a better way to use the Asp.Net-Membership in Adobe Flex and Actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I missed one detail. When I'm putting the .DLL in the weborb30/bin dir, the DLL will look for connections from the Web.config! So when I enabled my weborb web.config to connect to the database, it all worked out just fine.